# Get custom column value from sqlite table using SQLiteConnection

Tags: c#, sqlite, generics, .net-core

So i want to get the value from a column defined in the query using the sqlite object in .NET Core.

To clarify i want the value of cnt in following:

```
select count(*) as cnt from table
```

Here is the code. I know ["cnt"] is not going to compile but i hope its clear what i am trying to accomplish:

```
public static int Count<T>() where T : class, new() {
    var value = (int)Database.Query<T>($"select count(*) as cnt from {typeof(T).Name}")["cnt"];
}
```

In this case T is a model defined as such:

```
public class UserModel : BaseModel<UserModel> {
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

I know that i could do a select * ....Count but i don't want to return all rows from table into object and also would like to be able to get custom values from things besides count in the future.

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: What's the issue you are facing with this code?

Comment: I want the value of cnt. Cnt is not a column on the table so not sure how to access this value